# Data Mining: Clustering of nominal attributes through DBSCAN algo

Tags: python, r, cluster-analysis, data-mining

I want to perform clustering on a data set with DBSCAN algorithm. The problem is that the data has nominal attributes like zipcode and currency. Any idea how to handle these values?

Comment: Check this [question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130974/how-to-use-both-binary-and-continuous-variables-together-in-clustering)

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Define a custom distance function that handles these attributes as desired. For example with zip codes, you will want to look up proximity.
2. Use Generalized DBSCAN and define a custom neighbor predicate. It could require e.g. zip codes to be neighbors *and* attribute values to be similar.

Don't use one-hot encoding on zip codes. That does not make much sense. You might as well use Hamming distance on the categorical attributes, which is more efficient (see option 1).